Mocking an named export in Jest throws TypeError: ...is not a function
I have an IconFactory.ts which doesn't have a default export:
export class Icon {
  primary: string = "PR";
}

export interface IconFactory {
  createAsync(entity: Entity): Promise<Icon>;
}

export class MyIconFactory implements IconFactory {
  async createAsync(entity: Entity): Promise<Icon> {
    const icon = new Icon();
    //Some other logic
    return icon;
  }
}

And in my functionality code, Client.ts, I create an instance of MyIconFactory:
import {
  MyIconFactory,
  type Icon,
} from "IconFactory";
export async function createIcon(entity: Entity){
  const iconFactory = new MyIconFactory();
  await iconFactory.createAsync(entity);
}

I'm trying to write a unit test to test Client.createIcon(), by mocking IconFactory.createAsync() in Client.test.ts:
import {
  Icon,
  MyIconFactory,
} from "IconFactory";
import { createIcon } from "Client";
const mockIcon = new Icon();
const mockCreate = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(mockIcon);
jest.mock("IconFactory", () => {
  const originalModule = jest.requireActual(
    "IconFactory"
  );

  return {
    __esModule: true,
    ...originalModule,
    MyIconFactory: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
      return { createAsync: mockCreate };
    }),
  };
});
it("should create markers when consignment addresses are overridden", async () => {
  Entity entity = new Entity();
  const result = createIcon(entity);
  //...Assertions
});

But when this runs, it throws an error at await iconFactory.createAsync(entity);: TypeError: iconFactory.createAsync is not a function.
Am I doing something wrong here?
Thanks in advance.
I've also tried
jest.spyOn(IconFactory.prototype).mockResolvedValue(mockIcon);
But that just didn't mock at all. Client.createIcon() still used the original implementation in iconFactory.createAsync.

You can use jest.spyOn(), it's simpler than jest.mock()
import { Icon } from './IconFactory';
import { createIcon } from './Client';
import { Entity } from './Entity';
import { MyIconFactory } from './IconFactory';

it('should create markers when consignment addresses are overridden', async () => {
  const mockIcon = new Icon();
  const createAsyncSpy = jest.spyOn(MyIconFactory.prototype, 'createAsync').mockResolvedValue(mockIcon);

  const entity = new Entity();
  await createIcon(entity);
  expect(createAsyncSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(entity);
  createAsyncSpy.mockRestore();
});

